# Clear way of saying that one set of rules overrides another, if contradicts

Tags: meaning-in-context, writing, legalese

I'm working on updating a constitution, but as it is for a non-incorporated entity it doesn't have to be legally perfect.  I'm much more interested in clarity.

Here is what I have at the moment:

> If any of the regulations of the Guild, the rules of Societies
>   Council, or other provisions enrolled upon the Guild Statutes Book
>   should disagree with this any portion of this Constitution or with any
>   Regulations, then those rules shall be overruled.

*Regulation* is defined earlier in the document as

> a rule or law that is passed by committee, with on going consequences to the club.

Basically:

> If A,B, or C contradicts X or Y, then uses A, B or C instead

Comment: Note: you want "ongoing" not "on going".

Answer (score 5):

Suggestion:

> Rules of the Guild, the Societies  Council, or the Guild Statutes Book *supersede* any conflicting regulations in this Constitution.

Comment: I'm trying to say the opposite, so Subsede?
or reverse order

Comment: How about just reversing the order, then? I edited the answer to reflect what I think you are saying.

Comment: supercede is the right word.  A,B and C supercede X and Y.

Comment: @Jim: Actually *supersede* is the right word.

Comment: X can _supersede_ (_supercede_) Y only if X is instituted later than Y.  So, a constitutional amendment supersedes an article or clause of the original constitution.  But if a court strikes down a law as unconstitutional, the constitution cannot be said to have superseded that law.

Comment: @TimLymington- Maybe it's a AE/BrE thing or maybe it's just two alternate spellings either is fine by my dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for something like:

*In case of contradiction between:*

1. *the Constitution or Regulations, and*
2. *any rules or regulations instituted by the Guild, the Societies Council, or other provisions enrolled upon the Guild Statutes Book,*

*the Constitution and Regulations (1) will be definitive, and the rules, regulations, or other provisions (2) will be deemed void.*

Or:

*The Constitution and Regulations override, and may not be superseded by, any rules or regulations instituted by the Guild, the Societies Council, or other provisions enrolled upon the Guild Statutes Book.  Should a rule, regulation, or provision contradict the Constitution or Regulations, it will be deemed invalid and the Constitution and Regulations will remain in force.*

Comment: you are saying the opposite of my meaning.

Comment: You want the constitution to be overridden without special mechanisms (constitutional amendments frequently require a larger quorum and/or a larger percentage of votes in favour)?  Anyway, no problem, just change the last two lines of option 1 to _the rules, regulations, or other provisions (2) will be definitive, and relevant portions of the Constitution and Regulations (1) will become void._

Comment: That is correct, we are a suborganistation of the Societies Counsel (who is a sub- of the guild), who we have no ability to control.
If our constitution comes into breach, they can cut off 40% funding, and quietlikly freeze our funds, and kick us out of our clubroom.
(Though 20 clubs were found in breach this year, with no consequences beyond having to change there constitution)
The alternitive to putting a clause allowing the constitution to be overridden, is to incorperate all there know rules into the consituion, and change the constitution every time they change a rule. (totally do-able)

Comment: @oxinabox All clear, that makes more sense now.  The formulation in my previous comment should work then.

Answer (score 0):

On the basis that rules A are to be applied but rules X are to be ignored:

1. Rules A supersede rules B.
2. Rules A are to be preferred.
3. Rules A take precedence.

(1) is better if the makers of the new rules have the power to revoke or rescind the other rules or decisions.
If they have no such power, (2) or (3) are better.